# Single Dataflow PipeLine but Different parameter passing value getting failed

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to schedule the single dataflow will aggregate source to destination environment but our requirement is single data flow pipeline if we pass the parameter while trigger schedule. which means if I schedule A, i can pass the source raw folder details and other necessary information. similarly i can pass another schedule trigger B, i can pass the different parameter value. is it possible but i can see the failure. please advise.

Trigger (A) source ---> Dataflow ----> stage folder ---> copy activity(dynamic) ---> sql(on premise)

Trigger (B) source ---> Dataflow ----> stage folder ---> copy activity(dynamic) ---> sql(on premise)

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Job failed due to reason: at Source 'sourcedataflow': Missing column 'columnname'. The column in source configuration cannot be found in source data's schema. but if we run in debugger mode, the data loading perfectly

Comment: Could you share activities that you are doing in dataflow

Comment: just add source and doing select operation and then adding surrogate key finally sink to stag folder

Comment: here my source is dataverse to link the datalake which means azure synapse link.

Comment: Are you using sources of different schema when you trigger the same pipeline

Answer (score 0):

When you debug for say stage folder 1 as parameter  , are you setting the mapping ? Since its SQL as sink , I am assuming that you are  . Now in the debug mode pass parameter for stage folder 2 details , unless schema is same in the both the case , it will fail with the same error which you mentioned .